# Win 8 Touch Keyboard un-resize windows

Tags: windows-8, on-screen-keyboard

I have a client that uses the Touch Keyboard to type into our application which has a set size to it. Recently he reported that when he is done using the touch keyboard, the windows do not resize back to their normal size and half of their height is gone. I opened another program (Windows Notepad) on his computer and sized it fairly large, but not maximized, opened the keyboard an notepad shrunk in size so the keyboard didn't cover it all. When closing the keyboard, the notepad window did not resize to it's previous larger size.

Is there a way to enable the windows to resize back to their original size so a user doesn't have to constantly resize the windows themselves back to the size they want them at? I don't believe this client had this issue before, so I'm guessing it was a recent update that causes this?

Comment: I have Windows 8.0 with latest updates, but I can't observe this behavior. When I open touch keyboard by tapping its button in taskbar, no windows shrink. Is the system at your client Windows 8.0 or 8.1?

Comment: I believe it may be 8.1. I just tested on my Windows 8.1 Pro, with a significantly larger screen, when the keyboard docks it resizes the window, and when exiting the keyboard, the window retains the new size. If the keyboard is floating, it does not resize the windows at all.

Comment: OK, now I can reproduce it, too. Exactly as you said, the behavior depends on whether the keyboard is maximized ("docked") or it is in standard size ("floating") and these two modes are switched by maximize/restore icon in top right corner of the keyboard. And here is your answer, isn't it? Let him use his keyboard without maximizing and the things will be just like before – no windows shrunk. IMO the only thing that happened is that your client has maximized his touch keyboard without realizing it is connected to behavior of windows. Maybe you can add the answer to the question and accept it.

Comment: Seems more like of a cheap hack then an actual solution. I emailed him, waiting to hear back...

Comment: I think I could bet that **there was never different behavior of touch onscreen keyboard before**. If user will object, just ask him what was different before what is not available in floating mode now. I'd bet second time that he won't be able to name it.